# Asp TreeView OnTreeNodeExpanded event prevents treeview from expanding

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

While using asp:TreeView control on web form and populating the nodes in code behind, it expands and collapses as expected. However, when I added OnTreeNodeExpanded event it caused a postback but never fired the event tired to this event and prevented the node from expanding. I am trying to save the nodes that are expanded in session and restore the treeview expansion state when the user revisit the page. Any ideas how to accomplish this with this approach. 
Thanks!

Here is the code snippet:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvDevices" runat="server"  OnTreeNodeExpanded="TvDevices_OnTreeNodeExpandedCollapsed"     OnTreeNodeCollapsed="TvDevices_OnTreeNodeExpandedCollapsed"/>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in devices)
        {
            TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
            tn.Text = s.toString();
            tn.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;
            tvDevices.Ndes.Add(tn);
        }
        if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Session["tvDevicesState"] == null)
                    tvDevices.CollapseAll(); //Default to collapsed state
                else
                {
                    RestoreTreeViewState(tvDevices.Nodes, Session["tvDevicesState"] as List<string>);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tvDevices.CollapseAll();
            }

    }
private void SaveTreeViewState(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes, List<string> expandedList)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode treeNode in treeNodes)
        {
            if (treeNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                if (treeNode.Expanded.HasValue && treeNode.Expanded == true)
                {
                    expandedList.Add(treeNode.Text);
                }
                SaveTreeViewState(treeNode.ChildNodes, expandedList);
            }   
        }            
    }

    private void RestoreTreeViewState(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes, List<string> expandedList)
    {            
        foreach (TreeNode treeNode in treeNodes)
        {
            treeNode.Expanded = false;
            if (expandedList.Contains(treeNode.Text))
            {
                if (treeNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {                         
                    treeNode.Expanded = true;
                    RestoreTreeViewState(treeNode.ChildNodes, expandedList);
                }                 
            }                
        }
    }

    protected void TvDevices_OnTreeNodeExpandedCollapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                     
        List<string> expandedList = new List<string>();  

        SaveTreeViewState(tvDevices.Nodes, expandedList);
        Session["tvDevicesState"] = expandedList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the reason why the OnTreeNodeExpanded event was not fired. In my case, the reason was that there was no value property attached to the tree nodes. After adding a value to each node, the event was being fired.
Below is the working code.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvDevices" runat="server"  OnTreeNodeExpanded="TvDevices_OnTreeNodeExpandedCollapsed"     OnTreeNodeCollapsed="TvDevices_OnTreeNodeExpandedCollapsed"/>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        List<TreeNode> root = new List<TreeNode>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            root.Add(new TreeNode("Parent Node " + i, i.ToString()));
        }
        foreach (TreeNode tn in root)
        {
            tn.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("First Child", "first"));
            tn.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Second Child", "second"));                              
            tvDevices.Nodes.Add(tn);
        }
        tvDevices.CollapseAll(); //Collapse all nodes
        RestoreTreeViewState(tvDevices.Nodes, (List<string>)Session["tvState"] ?? new List<string>()); //Restore previously expanded nodes

}
private void SaveTreeViewState(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes, List<string> expandedList)
{
    foreach (TreeNode treeNode in treeNodes)
    {
        if (treeNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            if (treeNode.Expanded.HasValue && treeNode.Expanded == true)
            {
                expandedList.Add(treeNode.Value);
            }
            SaveTreeViewState(treeNode.ChildNodes, expandedList);
        }   
    }            
}

private void RestoreTreeViewState(TreeNodeCollection treeNodes, List<string> expandedList)
{            
    foreach (TreeNode treeNode in treeNodes)
    {

         if(expandedList.Count == 0)
            return;
        if (expandedList.Contains(treeNode.Value))
        {
            if (treeNode.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {                         
                treeNode.Expand();
                RestoreTreeViewState(treeNode.ChildNodes, expandedList);
            }                 
        }                
    }
}

protected void TvDevices_OnTreeNodeExpandedCollapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                     
    List<string> expandedList = new List<string>();  
    SaveTreeViewState(tvDevices.Nodes, expandedList);
    Session["tvDevicesState"] = expandedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you added an event-handler for the treeview's Expanded/Collapsed event, it triggers a postback now. Before the tree view's event handler is called, the Page_Load event handler gets called. Within the Page_Load event handler, check for the `Page.IsPostBack` first before performing operations on the tree-view control, such as collapsing it by default.

Comment: I have checked for IsPostBack but the event handler is still not fired.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the updated code containing the IsPostBack check?
Next, how is the event handler wired up? Do you have autoeventwireup=true in the Page directive, or is the event handler wired up to the event in the code-behind file (usually PageName.Designer.cs)?

Comment: I just updated the code and AutoEventWireUp is set to True in the webform.

Comment: I think you have it the other way round. It should be:
`if (!IsPostBack)
{

/*code for default state*/

}`

Comment: That's right, but the main issue here is that the expand event is not being fired.